# De-conflicting data strategies when associating two tables

Tags: sql, foreign-key-relationship

I have some tables that look like this:

```
+------------+------------+------------+----------------+----------+
| Locations  |  HotelsA   |  HotelsB   | HotelsB-People |  People  |
+------------+------------+------------+----------------+----------+
| LocationID | HotelAID   | HotelBID   | PersonID       | PersonID |
| Address    | HotelAName | HotelBName | HotelBID       | Name     |
|            | LocationID |            |                |          |
+------------+------------+------------+----------------+----------+
```

Currently, if I want to know what the address is of the hotel someone is staying at there is no way to make that association without manually looking through the names of HotelsA for something that looks similar enough to the name of HotelsB.

I would like to remove HotelBName and replace it with a foreign key to HotelAID (in this example it would actually make more sense to change HotelsB-People to HotelsAPeople, but there are additional columns that I have omitted for simplicity that prevent that solution from being viable in my particular case). The end result would look like this:

```
+------------+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+
| Locations  |  HotelsA   |   HotelsB   | HotelsB-People |  People  |
+------------+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+
| LocationID | HotelAID   | HotelBID    | PersonID       | PersonID |
| Address    | HotelAName | FK_HotelAID | HotelBID       | Name     |
|            | LocationID |             |                |          |
+------------+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+
```

HotelAName and HotelBName are likely very similar, but inconsistently so. You could have "Springfield Marriott" in one and "Marriott, Springfield" in the other, but there's no consistency (no guarantee anything is spelled correctly either).

Are there any strategies for how this could be done as well as considerations for how to make the applications that utilize this data continue to work during the time it takes to fix all of the data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add the `FK_HotelAID` column to the `HotelsB` table.  Assigning the correct id to that column will largely be a manual process, although you could try joining `HotelAName` to `HotelBName` to at least cover the ids for names that have a perfect match.  Your applications should continue to work while you do this.  After you've assigned all the ids in`HotelsB` you can define the foreign key and then delete the `HotelBName` column.  Of course, any references that the applications make to `HotelBName` will need to be modified.